# Produce MessageSource using TCP with Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

What is the best way to produce MessageSource in Spring Integration wih a TCP client, which is receiving some data from a server ?
My app is already wotking with data from FTP and SFTP, but I need to implements a version with TCP. In previous versions, the entry point was an `InboundChannelAdapter` like this :

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "channel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"))
public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource(
        @Autowired AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer<FTPFile> ftpInboundFileSynchronizer) {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
            ftpInboundFileSynchronizer);
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(repo));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<File>());
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `MessageSource` for the TCP. Just because TCP/IP is a streaming protocol so we have there continuously working listener via `MessageProducer`  implementation - `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter`. There is just need to declare plain `@Bean` definition for this one and use the proper `ConnectionFactory` and `MessageChannel` for injection.

Comment: You should also read about deserializers in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories) - they are used to parse the stream into discrete messages. By default, CRLF is used to indicate the end of a message (i.e. Telnet).

Comment: The TCP is working, but there is a way to set a `Poller`, to wait, for example, 10 messages to do the treatment ? I've added a `Transformer`, and a `ServiceActivator`, which is making the link with the rest of the app.